# Extracting features. Is it normal to have a lot of getters/setters in a class?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, getter-setter

I have a bunch of different `Feature` classes which calculate image features.
I have to extract from these classes "key features" that will be used packed together as a search key.
And I will also store parts of the `Feature` classes. I can't store entire feature classes because that would be quite inefficient.

Now, what I have thought of is writing a `Stored_features` class that puts together the "key features".
My layout is:

```
   Facial_features
   |      |       |
   |      V       |
   | .---Feature1 V   <|-- Abstract_feature
   | | .---Feature2   <|---'
   V V V
  Stored_features
```

My problem is that such a `Stored_features` class would have a lot of getters and setters and as far as I know, **getters and setters indicate bad design**. Is there an easily maintainable way to avoid too many getters and setters here?

The point is **I see my code get here very tightly coupled with this layout :(**

EDIT:

My code extract as requested.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

class Abstract_feature{
public:
  virtual void calculate()=0;
  virtual void draw(cv::Mat& canvas)=0;
  /// to put values into Stored_features
  virtual void registrate_key_values(Stored_features&) const=0;
};

class Facial_features : Abstract_feature{
public:
  virtual void calculate()
  { 
    es.calculate; sc.calculate; 
    /*etc but iterating over a list of Abstract_feature's*/
  }
  Stored_features get_stored_features() const
  {
    return sf.clone();
  }
private:
  Stored_features sf;
  Head_size es;
  Skin_color sc;
};

class Head_size : public Abstract_feature{
  //you can guess the impl.
};    

class Stored_features{
public:
  typedef enum{SKIN_COLOR=0, HEAD_SIZE_WIDTH,HEAD_SIZE_HEIGHT} Name;
public:
  void set_key_feature(Name, double value);
  cv::Mat get_feature_vector() const {return key_values;}
private:
  cv::Mat key_values;
  // and here would come other features eg.
  cv::Rect head_roi; // I don't search based on these. (So I should not use getters/setters?)
};
```

Added opencv for it is an opencv-based project anyway.

Comment: Could you post some code to clarify what you're doing?

Comment: If you are going to provide setters and getters for the members, just make the members public

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Unless you have good reason to assuming getters and setters will be beneficial for API and ABI future compatibility. But yeah, that's often not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of a class should be its own issue.

In this case I discovered that all I need is a `pack()` function for each feature class that removes all the data I do not want to store. Then I can store the classes as they are and don't have to care about their sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Many getters and setters are not by themselves an indication of bad design. However, they can be a hint your classes can be factorised in smaller classes. Take as example'customer' if you put all the name, address,delivery address fields in one class it would be a bad design, which you should split using an 'address' class.

I am not sure what your design is about, the point is if you need 100 getters because you have 100,unrelated fields use 100 getters

Comment: so you'd think I can expose attributes of `Stored_features` even if the majority of the classes only need those just for themselves?

Comment: Use protected and private for data that should not exposed outside the class or exposed in a controlled way. However, from your design it looks like you could consider either maps key-value to store your properties or try to abstract common properties like for example create "body part" with things like size, colour etc and then have head extend body part with the head-only features.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably think somewhat less `literal` about your features, and more in abstract and mathematical terms. You seem to describe a face as a combination of facial features, each computed using some procedure and each separate facial feature thus contributes one (or possibly a few) scalar values to a single feature vector. Therefore I would recommend to store your features as that: a vector. Use some vector class (std::vector might work, but you might consider to use a linear math library for reasons I will explain below).

You can still `extract` scalar facial features from these vectors if you want to do so. For example, if you have `N` features, than this can be saved in a `N`-dimensional column feature vector `x`. Now, you can write any linear extraction operator as a row vector or even matrix `A` and obtain your desired feature `f` as `f = A*x`. If you want to store these matrices and vectors, you could better use a library like Boost uBLAS.

Now, you should still somehow express your search query. Instead of using getters and setters you should then rewrite your search query also in an vector, and you can take for example the distance (Euclidean, Manhattan) to compute how well a stored face matches the query.

To summarize: develop your business logic in a more mathematical way because this gives you more freedom to extend the system later and also saves  you headaches because you don't have to think up good names for every single feature. And make a nice GUI so the user doesn't have to enter complicated mathematical formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This functionality you describe, would be the task of the `Facial_features` class. The individual custom features have to deal with providing the values. My main concern: their sizes are internal problems of those classes, see my answer.